# how to exchange with non-alphabetic characters in a sentense

Tags: java

Given a string, return the string with all spaces and non-alphabetic characters replaced
by the character ‘#’, e.g. “Hello, world!” becomes “Hello##world#”

Any one can tell me in Java?

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read [ask].  This is not a site where you post requirements, and someone does all your work.  If you don't show some level of effort, don't expect much in return.

Comment: That isn't an appropriate question for this site. You need to have at least some code and do your research and come here when you're stuck on a specific technical problem.  Not have someone design or write your code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you haven't done your research, I will just give you some pointers: The method you're looking for is `replaceAll(regex, newValue)` from the `String` class (see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)))

This [article](http://www.ocpsoft.org/opensource/guide-to-regular-expressions-in-java-part-1/) covers the basics for regular expressions (regex) in Java. This is enough for your task.